# How to override resource to another resource using key in XAML?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

First of all, I'm sorry for my poor English.

I want to change code below:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <AcrylicBrush
                        x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                        BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" 
                        TintColor="{ThemeResource SystemChromeAltHighColor}" 
                        TintOpacity="0.6" 
                        FallbackColor="{ThemeResource SystemChromeMediumColor}" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
                    <SolidColorBrush
                        x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                        Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorWindowColor}"  />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
```

to like this:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <??? 
            x:key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" 
            ???="{ThemeResource SystemControlChromeMediumAcrylicWindowMediumBrush}"
    </Page.Resources>
```

I have tried Setter, Style, ... but all failed.
How to implement what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, you could use StaticResource to convert above code.

```
<StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlChromeMediumAcrylicWindowMediumBrush"/>
```

For more detail please refer to [`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/staticresource-markup-extension) docuemnt .